# how to add a counter value to a label each time a row is selected

Tags: jquery

i have the following function, what i am trying to achive is that when a selection is made the counter must add my selections and display it as a notification as

[image]

```
function (result) {


        var counter = 0;

        if (result > 0 && result == $.Slip.lastCall) {
                    counter++;
                    var test = $('#notify').addClass("notification");
                    $("#increment").html(counter);


            $('#Slip .betHeader .loader').hide();
        }


    }
```

before function run:

```
 <span id="notify"><label id="increment"></label></span>
```

after function run

```
 <span id="notify" class="notification"><label id="increment">1</label></span>
```

the above is what i tried,when you click on one selection it adds to the above notification and shows a 1. when i click on the second selection it still remains at one, i am trying to ahchieve if its selected only once it should show the number one,if another selction is made it should show 2, then 3 and so on..
from the above function am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have initialized the counter variable inside the function.
Please find the answer below,

```
function (result) {
        var counter;

        if (result > 0 && result == $.Slip.lastCall) {

                    var test = $('#notify').addClass("notification");
                    counter = test.find('#increment').html();
                    if (!counter) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    $("#increment").html(counter);


            $('#Slip .betHeader .loader').hide();
        }


    }
```

Comment: i tried this now,it just adds multiple labels,but doesnt display any  number notifications

Comment: @john Please try once with the updated code. "test.find('#increment').html();"